# Identify server that made call to web service

Tags: sharepoint, service

I am working within an intranet environment. We have both a production and development sharepoint server (WSS 3).

We have a 3rd party workflow product which runs on top of sharepoint. It is installed on both the production and development sharepoint servers. The workflow product can call web services I have written which are hosted on our web server.

How would I have the web services determine which sharepoint server made the call to the web service, be it the production or development server?

I would then use this information to retrieve server specific information from web.config or database etc.

Currently the site hosting web services is setup to allow anonymous access so code such as

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

returns an empty string. If windows authenticaion is used it returns the identity of the currently logged in user, which is no use in identifying the server the call was made from.

I need a push in the right direction to address what I believe is probably a common scenario please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName`

Comment: Excellent! That does the trick. I can then use

    System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname)

to convert the returned IP to a host name.

Note : Need to turn anonymous access off on the site hosting web services for the code to work.